# Different date formats in single column, need to clean to MMDDYY in SAS

Tags: date, sas, format, informat

I have a column that has several different date formats in it:

Sunday, December 25, 2011
38236.58333336
4/23/200500:00
4/5/2006

It is really messy and I have been trying to standardize it using different steps and If, then statements to create a new variable with no luck.

Any tips would be really appreciated.

```
Data want;
set have;

if index(date,'/') then
date_clean= input(trim(date)||'/2020', mmddyy10.);

else date_clean=input(date,best12.)+'30-DEC-1899'D;
format date_clean yymmdd10.;
run;
```

this is the best one so far but it didn't work for the dates formatted like
Sunday, December 25, 2011. I've tried to compress the column to remove the days of the week, but that didn't really help too much either.

I've tried

```
data want;
   set have;
   date_clean = put(date, mmddyy10.);
   format date_clean mmddyy10.;
run;
```

and I get:The format $mmddyy10 was not found or could not be loaded because of the different characters in the column.

Basically I want the data too look like this:

```
Original Date                Cleaned Date
Sunday, December 25, 2011    12/25/2011
38236.58333336               09/06/2004
4/23/200500:00               04/25/2005
4/5/2006                     04/05/2006
```

Comment: You cannot attach a NUMERIC format, like MMDDYY to a CHARACTER variable, like would be generate by the PUT() function call.

Comment: Why not just fix the Excel sheet you read them from?

Comment: The excel sheet has over 4000 observations, so I was looking to streamline the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

The ANYDTDTE informat can make a GUESS at how to convert a lot of strings.  But it cannot figure out what to do with the day of the week part.  Or that time component that is not separated from the date string.

You could try just removing those extra characters. (Note: You will want to type out the other 4 days of the week into the Regular Expression.)

```
data have;
  input string $40.;
cards;
Sunday, December 25, 2011
38236.58333336           
4/23/200500:00           
4/5/2006                 
;


data want;
  set have;
  date=input(string,??32.);
  if not missing(date) then date=int(date)+'30dec1899'd;
  if missing(date) then date=input(prxchange('s/MONDAY|TUESDAY|SUNDAY//i',-1,string),anydtdte40.);
  if missing(date) then date=input(tranwrd(string,'00:00 ',' '),anydtdte40.);
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    string                             date

 1     Sunday, December 25, 2011    2011-12-25
 2     38236.58333336               2004-09-06
 3     4/23/200500:00               2005-04-23
 4     4/5/2006                     2006-04-05
```

PS  Do not display dates in either MDY or DMY order or you will just have more confusion on your hands.  **Is that last string the fourth of May or April fifth?** Use either YMD order or the style printed by the DATE9. format.

Comment: Thank you! When I run this code i get "The format $YYMMDD was not found or could not be loaded."

Comment: Not the code I posted.  The only reason would if you accidentally tried to attach the YYMMDD format to a CHARACTER variable.  You cannot change the type of a variable. You will need to make new variable to store date values.  You could later rename the variables if you want.